# getViewId(), getServletPath() and getRequestURI() all returns previous URL, how to get current URL?

Tags: jsf

In my JSF 2.1 project, I need to get the current URL and I used `FacesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId()` but it always returns the previous URL.

I also tried `request.getServletPath()` and `request.getRequestURI()` but the result was same.

Comment: Explain the difference between 'current' and 'previous' URL. These methods all work as expected for me.

Comment: Actually in JSF, when we navigate from one page to another page 'request.getServletPath()' gives URL of previous page from which we have migrated. And I want to get the URL of Current Page.

Comment: Eg . If currently i am on '/sample/pages/homePage.xhtml' and if i click on a button, the website redirects to a second page '/sample/pages/workList.xhtml' but the url indicates '/sample/pages/homePage.xhtml' only until i refresh the web page. 'request.getServletPath()' and other such methods gives the result as '/sample/pages/homePage.xhtml' even when i was redirected to '/sample/pages/workList.xhtml'.